# Sleep in Smalltalk Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm dealing with N*N queens problem and gui of it.
I want to sleep for a few seconds each move so the viewer can see the process.
How do I put smalltalk to sleep?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of sleeping you can just wait.

```
5 seconds asDelay wait.
```

e.g. if you select and *print it* the following, it will wait 5 seconds before printing the result (2)

```
[
    5 seconds asDelay wait.
    1 + 1
] value
```

The comment of the `Delay` class explains what it does.

> I am the main way that a process may pause for some amount of time.  The simplest usage is like this:
>
> (Delay forSeconds: 5) wait.
>
> An instance of Delay responds to the message 'wait' by suspending the caller's process for a certain amount of time. The duration of the pause is specified when the Delay is created with the message forMilliseconds: or forSeconds:. A Delay can be used again when the current wait has finished. For example, a clock process might repeatedly wait on a one-second Delay.
>
> A delay in progress when an image snapshot is saved is resumed when the snapshot is re-started. Delays work across millisecond clock roll-overs.
>
> For a more complex example, see  #testDelayOf:for:rect: .

**Update:** (based on comment)

`wait` will pause the execution flow, which means that in the example earlier, the `1 + 1` will get executed (execution flow resumed) only after the wait period has ended.

So in your class you can have...

```
MyBoard>>doStep
    self drawBoard.
    5 seconds asDelay wait.
    self solve.
    5 seconds asDelay wait.
    self destroyBoard.
```

Comment: how exactly does the wait work? I instantiate my board and draw it, then i want it to wait x seconds, start solve, wait x seconds, then delete the board. Im not sure i understand exactly when the wait happens and when the next/previous command happens

Comment: @Infested I've added the class comment of the Delay class.

Comment: @Infested and another update... if I understand your comment correctly.

Comment: Thanks, yes you did answer my question!

Comment: I do see something strange though, I print solutions in the form of permutation on the transcript (in solve method) and draw it as well as gui. when I do draw wait solve, it draws at the same time it starts to solve. any idea why?

Comment: @Infested maybe the UI loop is being executed in a different process? I don't know without seeing the code (maybe best to ask a separate question with a real code sample).

Comment: I dont really know which part to show, is there any way to send you the code and you look at it and tell me why it acts that way?

Comment: Well stackoverflow has a chat or something like that... but a pastebin link might suffice.

Comment: do you have an answer?